# Clicking a child doesn't trigger the parent's :active state in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, pseudo-class

I have found an irritating bug in IE 8-10 that prevents a parent's active state being triggered. It appears that if a child of the parent element is the target of the click event the active state on the parent element is not triggered.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/WilsonPage/6FYFj/1/). If you click the text inside the `<li>` the element wont change colour. If you click inside an `<li>` anywhere other than on the `<p>` child the element will turn blue.

This is a problem as it pretty much renders the css :active pseudo state useless in IE if the element has any children.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and even better found a way round it?

Comment: I suppose you could trigger it in JQuery? If there's no CSS workaround of course

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7820740/css-selector-active-not-working-on-child-element-click-in-ie8

Comment: Not a duplicate; this is for any child element (`img` child elements can be replaced with background images), and the other question doesn't have any generic answers posted

Comment: Found [two](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3526206/css-active-pseudo-class-target-child-elements-in-ie?rq=1) [more](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2769392/a-with-an-inner-span-not-triggering-active-state-in-ie-8) questions which also work around the problem by removing the child elements or by using JS

Comment: the problem with IE8 is that you can't view correctly jsfiddle.net :P

Comment: I'm only familiar with IE through ver 8 but I do know that in IE8 actions only propagate in the capture phase that is if you click on something that responds to a click such as a link and the link is in a <a> which is in a <li> which is in a <ul> which is in a <div> the browser first checks the <div> then the <ul> and so on to see if it's listening for a click.  IE only has a capture phase all other browsers also have a bubbling phase which start with the innermost clicked on item and go up the DOM.  I don't know if this is what you need but check it out.

Comment: For the future reader, this bug is still present in IE9-11 in 2018, your best bet is to fix it via JS (mousedown/mouseup events).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an easy workaround: add a css rule to the paragraph.

**[Working example](http://jsfiddle.net/6FYFj/23/)**

**CSS**

```
ul { list-style: none; }
li { height: 50px; margin-bottom: 4px; background: red; }
li:active { background: blue; }
p:active { background: blue; height: 100%;}
```

Comment: Why you need an extra div? When you can just add p:active {
   background: blue;
   height: 100%;
} to the p tag itself.

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed the issue by preventing pointer-events on the child element. This way the `:active` state is triggered directly on the parent and doesn't need to be propagated. The only downside of this solution is you cannot attach an event listener (not even a css `:hover selector) to the child anymore. So you have to move all your event listeners to the parent.

```
.child { pointer-events: none; }
```

Here is jsFiddle https://jsbin.com/govelabuca/1/edit?css,output
Just uncomment the last line in css and compare the result in IE and other modern browser

Answer (score 0):

You could add another CSS selector for the `<p>` tag so your

```
li:active { background: blue; }
```

will become

```
li:active, li p:active { background: blue; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you would use javascript or jquery for that when you click a child element, perform the active state of of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

I've stumbled upon this on IE11. I was writing a drag-n-drop styling logic using this approach suggested by [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213733/6509119).

In my case I have a row with `td` cell elements and using `:active` for the parent `tr` does the job for other browsers. For IE, I've added a CSS rule to target the cells (`tr.myRowClass > td:active`) and modified the if condition in my custom JS logic executed during the `mousemove` event handler of the cells:

```
 if (style.getPropertyValue('cursor') == 'auto' || document.querySelectorAll(":active").length > 0) {
```

The remaining task is to find the target element:
[Determine which element the mouse pointer is on top of in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813051/determine-which-element-the-mouse-pointer-is-on-top-of-in-javascript)