# How to select all sibling selectors of a certain class, both before and after the active element?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have not been able to find an answer for this, so here goes:

I have 4 divs on the page. When one div is :active, I want all the other divs to adopt `opacity:0;`

has anyone come up with a way to select all siblings, not just siblings that come after the `:active` element?

```
<div class="circle c1"> </div>
<div class="circle c2"> </div>
<div class="circle c3"> </div>
<div class="circle c4"> </div>

<style type="text/css">

    .c2:active ~.circle {
        opacity: 0;
    }
</style>
```

From this example, the .c1 div will never disappear. What is a solution that uses only CSS?

Comment: You could just select siblings that come **after a given element**. At least using just CSS. Do you really mean `:active` state and not `:hover`?

Comment: try something like `.c2:active ~.circle:nth-child(n)`

Comment: @Morpheus: `:nth-child(n)` is effectively useless here in that it won't change which elements match (and which don't).

Answer (score 1):

This is *sort of* possible, but not wonderfully so and, incidentally, I'm using `:hover` instead of `:active`:

```
.circle {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 48%;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    height: 10em;
}

body:hover .circle {
    opacity: 0.4; /* obviously adjust to 0, but used 0.4 for the demonstration */
}

body:hover .circle:hover {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/KLgb4/).

It works by selecting all the elements to style as `opacity: 0` based on the `:hover` of their shared parent (`body` in the example code), and then selecting the currently-hovered `div` to override that styling.

In the demo I've used `:hover`, but you could, if you wish, use `:active`, but I'm not sure what you want to achieve with that. Still, it's a proof-of-concept.

Comment: Thanks David. This might work. I will just create a parent element for the circles and use the :hover on that instead of the body.

Comment: This will probably not work with `:active` due to issues with IE (see for example [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10753215/clicking-a-child-doesnt-trigger-the-parents-active-state-in-ie) which has other links in the comments). Basically, `body:active .circle:active` will not work in IE, as the parent is not considered active when the child is active.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I really needed :hover instead. I've seen that :active IE bug before, and recently even. Thanks again.